# Change video name in Powerpoint using regex in vba

Tags: vba, video, powerpoint

I'm trying to search all the videos on my presentation and change the extension of each video; changing from XXXX.mp4 to XXXX.wmv and vice versa but whenever I get to the regex part I get an error on the "pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName"

```
Sub Test()

    Dim pptSlide As Slide
    Dim pptShape As Shape
    Dim Regx As Object
    Dim regX_matches As Object


    Set Regx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With Regx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = ".*"
    End With

    For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes
            If pptShape.Type = msoMedia Then
                If pptShape.MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie Then
                    Set regX_matches = Regx.Execute(pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName)
                    Debug.Print "TEST '" + regX_matches + "'"
                    If regX_matches <> "" Then
                        pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = regX_matches(0) + ".mp4"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next pptShape
    Next pptSlide

End Sub
```

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Edit1: My videos are embedded so as JamieG said pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName won't work...  Any idea how to modify embedded videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the error? I managed to generate the following error by trying to return the SourceFullName property for an embedded (not linked) video so are your videos linked or embedded?

```
LinkFormat (unknown member) : Invalid request. This operation requires a linked object.
```

You can add a test for this by using the following property of the shape:

```
pptShape.MediaFormat.IsLinked
```

So:

Sub Test()

```
Dim pptSlide As Slide
Dim pptShape As Shape
Dim Regx As Object
Dim regX_matches As Object


Set Regx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With Regx
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = ".*"
End With

For Each pptSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each pptShape In pptSlide.Shapes

        If pptShape.Type = msoMedia Then
            If pptShape.MediaType = ppMediaTypeMovie And pptShape.MediaFormat.IsLinked Then
                Set regX_matches = Regx.Execute(pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName)
                Debug.Print "TEST '" + regX_matches + "'"
                If regX_matches <> "" Then
                    pptShape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = regX_matches(0) + ".mp4"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next pptShape
Next pptSlide
```

End Sub

Comment: My bad... My videos are embedded...I'm just starting with vba on Powerpoint (I had experiencie in Excel) but I'm struggling to find proper information about shapes. "videos". I had found plenty of examples about how to replace stings and text boxes but no videos... My apologies

Comment: No problem. Finding good documentation on VBA (not VB) and/or the associated Object Model or the app in use isn't easy! By the way, did my IsLinked code modification answer your question? If so, please feel free to upvote the answer.